# Calculating the average of integers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, average

I must calculate the average of the integers inside the array:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("How many elements do you want to add in to the array? --> ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    float array[10];
    float total, average;

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        printf("Insert the element: ");
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
        total = total + array[i];
    }

    average = total/num;
    printf("The average is: %.2f\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
How many elements do you want to add in to the array?  --> 3
Insert the element: 5
Insert the element: 6
Insert the element: 7
The average is: 18.00
```

I expected the output to be `6.00`, but it's `18.00`. How do I fix this?

Comment: First: initialize `total`: `float total = 0;` or simply `total = 0;` before the loop.

Comment: `printf("The average is: %.2f\n", average);`

Comment: Your compiler should show some warning about unused variable `average`. Listen to your compiler warnings.

Comment: If it's supposed to be an array of integers, why did you make it an array of floats instead?

Comment: Also, what if the user enters a number larger than 10 for the number of elements to add to the array? (Hint: do you really even need an array?)

Comment: If all you want is the average of a sequence, you don't even need the array; just an accumulator and a counter. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float avg,sum=0;
    int i;
    float marks[3];//array declaration
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        printf("enter marks\n");
        scanf("%f",&marks[i]); //store data in array
        printf("you have entered %f\n",marks[i]);
        sum=sum+marks[i];
    }
    printf("\nou have entered sum=%f\n",sum);
    avg=sum/3;
    printf("average marks=%f\n",avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: float total=0; //you missed this as total may take an garbage value initially and so can alter your total=total is (initial some garbage value) + arr[i];

Comment: you must store total=0+arr[0] //for i=0 in your loop

Comment: total=arr[0]+arr[1] //for i=1 in your loop and so on... you will get correct value of total as i have shown in my program with variable sum=0